# Gradle build get stuck after update android studio to 2.1.3 version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

before updating android studio, my gradle version was 2.10 and gradle    plugin version was 2.1.0 and every things work fine. Unfortunately    after updating android studio and android gradle plugin to 2.1.3,    android studio can't build project and get stuck in gradle build    running!

this is my project build.gradle code snippet:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and currenly my gradle version is 2.14.1. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. It seems your gradle works in online mode. you must switch it to offline mode. In Android Studio open the settings and search for `offline`. in the Gradle sub category and Global gradle settings section, you will see `Offline work` check box.check it to force gradle works offline.

good luck.

Comment: are you trying this? disconnect your internet connection and rebuild your project. try this and tell me the result

Comment: yes, i think there is a problem with proxy server! because i can't fetch repositories list in sdk manager!

Comment: for fetching repositories from sdk manager, after running a http proxy changer application (like free gate) your ip and port number has been changed, so you must set sdk manager proxy setting as same as your internet option proxy, then it's work. maybe setting the proxy for android studio have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

this way worked for me :

1. delete .gradle folder in your project folder
2. make sure that your system proxy is enable(for iranian user!)
3. enable Auto-detect proxy setting at :

   ```
   File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior -- System Settings -- HTTP Proxy
   ```
4. Go to gradle.properties file (project root directory) and add these options (for both `http` and `https`):

   ```
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
   systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
   systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
   systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain

   systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
   systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
   systemProp.https.proxyUser=user
   systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
   systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
   systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
   ```

   but i config this form(because i use psiphon)

   ```
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.01
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
   systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
   systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
   ```
5. make sure that your gradle not be in offline mode then select `use default gradle wrapper...` in :

   ```
    File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
   ```
6. Now `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

I hope that I have helped